# What's the point of using unscope in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What's the point of using `unscope` in rails.

In the examples [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#unscope) they use the following code

```
Article.where('id > 10').limit(20).order('id asc').unscope(:order)

# which gives
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id > 10 LIMIT 20

# and this without unscope
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id > 10 ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 20
```

But why not just remove the  `.order('id asc')` part:

```
Article.where('id > 10').limit(20)
```

Comment: What about default scoping?

Suppose that you have default scope on a model. But for admin end you don't need this scoping.

Comment: Also keep mind it has since been deprecated see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII, that is a different thing. I'm talking about [unscope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/unscope)

Comment: oops, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But why not just remove `.order('id asc')`

I would say, that one of the reasons, is that you might simply not have access to the original query, so the only way for you to "modify" it, is to use `unscope`.

For example,

```
Article.where('id > 10').limit(20).order('id asc')
```

might very well be a part of some external gem as some scope, so you have to work with it as is. And here is when `unscope` comes to the rescue.